# how to tell typescript that given input would have a subset of expected type

Tags: typescript, nestjs, prisma

I am using nestjs with prisma and after migrating the schema.prisma, many Prisma types got automatically generated. I am not sure about what exactly is the correct way to use the generated types but I am using the generated types on service file and my own Dto for controller for validations. However, this is giving problems like:

> Type 'number | IntFieldUpdateOperationsInput' is not assignable to
> type 'number'.   Type 'IntFieldUpdateOperationsInput' is not
> assignable to type 'number'.

this type IntFieldUpdateOperationsInput was autogenerated by prisma for the @default(autoincrement()). However, I don't think I even need this for my use case as only number type for id would suffice.

```
  export type IntFieldUpdateOperationsInput = {
    set?: number
    increment?: number
    decrement?: number
    multiply?: number
    divide?: number
  }
```

**category.service.ts**

```
  ...
  update({ id, name }: Prisma.MainCategoryUncheckedUpdateInput) {
    return this.prismaService.mainCategory.update({
      where: { id },
      data: { name },
    });
  }
  ...
```

**category.controller.ts**

```
  ...
  @Patch(':id')
  update(
    @Param('id') id: string,
    @Body() updateCategoryDto: UpdateCategoryDto,
  ) {
    return this.categoryService.update({ id: +id, ...updateCategoryDto });
  }
  ...
```

**Schema.prisma**

```
datasource db {
  provider = "sqlite"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

model User {
  id           Int            @id @default(autoincrement())
  email        String         @unique
  username     String         @unique
  password     String
  isAdmin      Boolean
  mainCategory MainCategory[]

  projects Project[]
}

model TechStack {
  id             Int           @id @default(autoincrement())
  name           String        @unique
  description    String?
  MainCategory   MainCategory? @relation(fields: [mainCategoryId], references: [id])
  mainCategoryId Int?
  technologies   Technology[]
}

model MainCategory {
  id          Int         @id @default(autoincrement())
  name        String      @unique
  description String?
  User        User?       @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId      Int?
  techStack   TechStack[]
}

model Technology {
  id          Int                   @id @default(autoincrement())
  name        String                @unique
  description String?
  status      String
  stars       Int
  TechStack   TechStack?            @relation(fields: [techStackId], references: [id])
  techStackId Int?
  projects    ProjectTechnologies[]
}

model Project {
  id           Int                   @id @default(autoincrement())
  name         String                @unique
  description  String?
  link         String
  technologies ProjectTechnologies[]
  User         User?                 @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId       Int?
}

model ProjectTechnologies {
  project      Project    @relation(fields: [projectId], references: [id])
  projectId    Int // relation scalar field (used in the `@relation` attribute above)
  technologies Technology @relation(fields: [technologyId], references: [id])
  technologyId Int // relation scalar field (used in the `@relation` attribute above)

  @@id([projectId, technologyId])
}
```

From the error shown, it is certain that a number would is definitely expected. But is there a way of telling typescript that its okay to get just a number only without having to write extra code? or altering the auto generated file in any way?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new type using the generated definition of `MainCategoryUncheckedUpdateInput` where the `id` field is of type `number`.

```js
type customCategoryUpdateInput = Omit<Prisma.MainCategoryUncheckedUpdateInput, "id"> & {
    id?: number; // redifining id to be of type number only 
};
```

The [omit utility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) is used to first erase the original type definition of `id` in `MainCategoryUncheckedUpdateInput` before redefining it. Now you can use `customCategoryUpdateInput` in place of `Prisma.MainCategoryUncheckedUpdateInput` in your service file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I was hoping for something where i wouldn't have to create more types than there are already. For now, I think better solution in my case would be to create another variable within the service method itself, like "const stringTypeName = name as string" where "{ name, ...rest }: Prisma.MainCategoryUpdateInput". Prisma.MainCategoryUpdateInput has the same problem as above. It has an extra seemingly unnecessary type in it.

Comment: I understand. What you're saying should work as well. Unfortunately to the best of my knowledge, there's no "elegant" solution to type mismatches like these :/